# Whether to use an apostrophe after 'Games'

Tags: apostrophe

Should the following sentence have an apostrophe after 'Games'? I feel like it should as it's referring to plural 'games'.

> More tickets were applied for than at all previous Paralympic Games combined.

Comment: There is no need for an apostrophe, since it's used to indicate **[possession](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_possessive)**.

Comment: The sentence doesn't look very good. Did you write it yourself? What is the source of the sentence?

Comment: @Rathony - what was so bad in including the full sentence in the title? I did it because I thought that that would make it easier for users to know right away what the question is about.

Comment: @CopperKettle Nothing wrong with it. If you click on ***questions***, the sentence appears. The subject doesn't need to contain it as it is too long. One more thing, the sentence is not ***good***.

Comment: @Rathony - Why do you think it doesn't look good?  It would help a new English learner to know *why* you think it isn't good.  It looks fine to me.

Comment: @stangdon I don't think ***at*** should be placed there. ***Than*** is functioning as a "***quasi***-relative pronoun" or ***preposition*** if you will. And there is no reason to put ***at*** there grammatically. Do you think it is OK?

Comment: @stangdon I would really appreciate your answer to my question. Why do you think it looks fine to you?

Comment: @Rathony The sentence looks fine to me too. Still I think it should have been "***More tickets were applied for than at all the previous Paralympic Games combined.***"

Comment: @Mrstupid Yes, that is another point that I was going to ask him. Do you mean without ***at***, it doesn't make sense?

Comment: @Rathony It does. or maybe it doesn't, as it looks fine to the native speaker. :) PS - I am not a native speaker.

Comment: @Rathony -  As originally phrased, it says: "**More tickets were applied for**" (a passive-voice phrase) "**than**" (a function word that indicates a comparison) "**at all previous...**" (what we are comparing the first thing to).  You could say that the original sentence elides "...than **were applied for** at all previous...  The sentence requires "at" because the action happened **at** the games.  Without "at", it would mean "*the number of tickets applied for was higher than the number of previous games*" which means something completely different.

Comment: @stangdon I beg to differ. The full sentence would be "More tickets were applied for than ***(the tickets of)*** all the previous Olympics combined". Nobody would interpret that way as there were not many Paralympic Games were held and the main point of the sentence is about "the number of tickets". In a comparison sentence, it is common to omit repeated words after "than", i.e. More Olympic Games were held in London than New York. You don't need to use ***at or in*** before New York even though *at/in* modifies a specific place. *At* in the above sentence is meaningless and not required.

Answer (score 4):

Apostrophes are to be used only for possession and not plural
So, answering your question, **no**.

Although, there are exceptions, check out [this for more information on apostrophe usage](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/secondary/harts_rules/4-2-apostrophe)!

Comment: Apostrophes are used to pluralize numbers, alphabets, or acronyms.

Comment: Clearly in this case, it wasn't a number @Rathony

Comment: Your answer might be misleading as you didn't specify its usage and do you think the sentence is all right?

Comment: Thanks for the answers. And no, I didn't write this sentence myself. I saw it on a website.

Comment: @DuncanCarr Can you post the link? I can't find the sentence.